# Sending SMS with delivery message

Tags: c#, c++, windows-mobile, sms, mapi

How can i write code for send SMS with delivery message in Windows Mobile? please guide me with C# or C++ code.
I want to use SmsSendMessage API in this code because this API have more features.

Comment: Just a note that even tho you may request a delivery report you may not get one.  It's up to the network support delivery reports and I have found most do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [SmsSendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa455068.aspx) to send the message and use [SmsGetMessageStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa455061.aspx) to get the status report of the sent SMS. This is all C++ code, but you can pinvoke it as well.

Comment: Which parameters must be used in calling SmsSendMessage API for delivery?

Comment: In the pbProviderSpecificData parameter you can set the Notification_Provider_Specific_Data struct: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa919471.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook Namespace

The Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook namespace provides classes that allow you to create and access PIM data items (Appointments, Tasks, and Contacts), and MAPI messaging items (e-mail and SMS messages), on mobile devices

[SmsMessage Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.smsmessage.aspx) in msdn

This sample shows how to send an SMS message to a mobile phone.

```
public void SmsMessageSend()
{
    SmsMessage smsMessage = new SmsMessage();

    //Set the message body and recipient.
    smsMessage.Body = "Would you like to meet for lunch?";
    smsMessage.To.Add(new Recipient("John Doe", "2065550199"));
    smsMessage.RequestDeliveryReport = true;

    //Send the SMS message.
    smsMessage.Send();

    return;
    }
```